# How to distinguish between new objects created and found objects with mongo

Tags: mongodb, findandmodify

According to the [mongo docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/), my return object should contain a lastErrorObject, which should indicate if the object is new or old, through updatexisting. I do not see this object. How can I fix my query in order to distinguish between new objects created and found objects?

```
 db['posts'].find_and_modify({:query=>{"id"=>post_hash["id"]}, :update=>post_hash, :upsert=>true})
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Can you post the response you're getting?

Comment: its nothing special. its simply my document with no meta data

Answer (score 3):

The documentation to which you refer is not specific to the ruby driver. Try adding the :full_response=>true option as documented here:

http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#find_and_modify-instance_method

It should return a hash with the requested document ("value") and a "lastErrorObject" hash with a field "updatedExisting" that you can check. Hope that helps.